# Linked list returning variables from a function

Tags: c++, function, linked-list, return-value

Hi i am doing a project for college and i am stuck at a part. I am using linked list in c++. I have to set up a class called Book which has variables 'title', 'author', 'ISBN' and 'availability'. I set it up like this in my main using a prototype for the function and the function being called elsewhere.

```
//the prototype
list<Book> bookSetUp();
int main()
{
//the variable in main that will have the list
list<Book> bookList;
//the list being populated in function elsewhere so as to not mess up the main
bookList = bookSetUp();
// more stuff in main 
}
//sets up the book vector list by populating it
//title, author, ISBN, availability
list<Book> bookSetUp()
{
//creates a temp vector to pass it back to the actual vector to be used in the main
list<Book> temp;
//The items that populate the list
Book a("A Tale of Two Cities", "Charles Dickens", 1203456, true);
Book b("Lord of the rings", "J.R.R Tolkein", 123456, true);
Book c("Le Petit Prince", "Antoine de Saint-Exupéry", 123457, true);
Book d("And Then There Were None", "Agatha Christie", 123458, true);
Book e("Dream of the Red Chamber","Cao Xueqin",123459, true);
Book f("The Hobbit","J.R.R Tolkein",123467, true);
//pushes the items into the vector
temp.push_back(a);
temp.push_back(b);
temp.push_back(c);
temp.push_back(d);
temp.push_back(e);
temp.push_back(f);

//returns the list
list<Book>::iterator pos;
pos = temp.begin();
while(pos != temp.end())
{
return pos;
if(pos != temp.end())
{
pos++;
}
}
}
```

I know that my links between files are grand i just cant get the 'temp' list to return the values. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do in the `while(pos != temp.end())` loop?  It currently immediately returns `temp.begin()`

Comment: sorry about the mass of code!I feel its better than trying to communicate everything

Comment: hmm. and what exactly are you trying to do? i have a feeling that you want something like what 'yield' does in some languages

Comment: I set the pos equal to the beginning of the list `pos = temp.begin();` so that it is incremented to the next item on the list unless it has reached the end `pos != temp.end()`

Im am trying to get the function bookSetUp() to fill the list in the main list<Book> bookList.

I should have stated this in my question the main is in `main.cpp` and bookSetUp() is in another .cpp called `functions`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ most containers like `std::list` can be copy-constructed or assigned just like any other primitive types. In your case a direct `return` is enough.